# How to monitor SQL Server database jobs with Grafana Dashboard

Tags: sql-server, database, grafana

We have more than 200 SQL Server database jobs. I want to monitor them using Grafana. I tried Grafana with IIS Logs monitoring but no idea about SQL Server database jobs monitoring. Right now we have in place DB Job which will gather information about database jobs running on server but I am not able to find useful metrics to show on Grafana Dashboard.

In case of API we have no of hits or how much time API time taken to complete API call. But I am not able to find any suitable metrics in case of SQL Server database jobs. We want to monitor DB Jobs running with number of memory consumed like those stats.

Please help me to understand useful DB Jobs metrics to show on Grafana Dashboard.

Comment: This isn't a programming question. Grafana isn't a monitoring tool either, it visualises time series collected by *other* systems like Prometheus, InfluxDB etc. If you search For SQL Server monitoring using those tools you'll find a lot of information.

Comment: For example, [this article](https://www.olivercoding.com/2018-09-18-mssql-prometheus/) describes how to use a [SQL Server Exporter](https://github.com/DanielOliver/mssql_exporter) to provide metrics to Prometheus

Comment: Yes,agree. We are using one DB Jobs to gather metrics from SQL DB Jobs views. But I am not able to understand which metrics of DB Jobs are useful  to visualize on Grafana, apart from execution time and running timestamp.

Comment: In that case you need to learn about monitoring SQL Server, using SQL Server's own dashboards, before trying to use another monitoring tool. Right click on the server node in SSMS and click on `Reports`. Same for each database, the `SQL Server Agent` job etc. Jobs don't consume memory by themselves, it's the queries they run that take memory. You'll find that in the server, DB reports